# JQuery carousel resume issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I am using JQuery Simple Carousel, and it's doing everything fine (auto play, fading between each list item, prev and next buttons)...but the issue is that when I click on a button it stops the auto play.  I would like to find a solution where once clicked, the carousel starts up again in twice the amount of time it would normally take to auto play for that one time. here's the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        // Carousel 
        $("ul.writein").simplecarousel({
            width:692,
            height:148,
            auto: 5000,
            fade: 700,
            next: $('.next'),
            prev: $('.prev')
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in following code part:

```
if(typeof click != "undefined")
config.auto = false;
```

Which effectively stops the carousel after you use any of it's navigation. 
To fix that you'll need:

**Edited to add animation timeout resetting**:

Add variables that will store timeout and if the timeout is active:

```
var myTimer, timerActive = false;
```

right after `var li = ul.children('li');`

replace:

```
if(typeof click != "undefined")
            config.auto = false;

        if(config.auto!=false)
            setTimeout(function() {
                slide('next');
            }, config.auto);
```

with:

```
if(typeof click != "undefined"){
    if(config.auto!=false){
        if (timerActive) clearTimeout(myTimer);
        myTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                slide('next');
            }, config.auto * 2);
        }
        timerActive = true;
    }
    else{
        if(config.auto!=false){
            if (timerActive) clearTimeout(myTimer);
            myTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                slide('next');
            }, config.auto);
            timerActive = true;
        }
    }
```

and at the very end of the carousel code replace:

```
if(config.auto!=false)
        setTimeout(function() {
            slide('next');
        }, config.auto);
```

with:

```
if(config.auto!=false){
            if (timerActive) clearTimeout(myTimer);
            myTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                slide('next');
            }, config.auto);
            timerActive = true;
        }
```

**----end edit----**

Please note that I haven't actually tested any of this - there might be typos etc.
If it doesn't work you can always try carousel for jQuery I wrote https://github.com/c2h5oh/jQuery-Cycle-Uber-Lite

Comment: Thank you, It looks like this is starting to achieve the result for sure, but it's acting a little strange.  When hitting previous or next the slide that appears only shows up for a quick moment then quickly goes to the next slide which is back on time, then every other slide is quick like the first one

Comment: That's because the change didn't reset the timeout that was already set - it would have to be saved to variable ( `var x = setTimeout()` ) so `clearTimeout(x)` could be used.

Comment: i am a newb, and I can't get clearTimeout(x) to work for me... could you please show me what the script completed would look like?

Comment: that was just an example - edited the answer to include timeout resetting.